# How should I connect a furnace fan to a start capacitor?

Tags: electrical, electric-motor

I have an old squirrel cage that works but capacitor is missing. The motor has 3 wires (red/white/blue). How do I hook this up with a run/start cap?

Comment: If you get this running, I have been told to be sure to load the fan by restricting the inlet orifice. The motor on an unloaded fan will over-speed and overheat. I once ruined the motor on a water fan by running it without the water carrying pad in place.

Answer (score 0):

You need to determine if the motor actually uses a capacitor. Look on the motor for a picture of the wiring required. The capacitor size is usually shown. The motor you have may be a shaded pole, split phase, or have a capacitor  inside the motor housing. "GOOGLE" the motor number of the motor for more motor information. You may have a 2 speed motor that does not require a capacitor. Then as @Jim Stewart said, make sure you check the motor amperage and restrict the air  inlet so as not to overload the motor. A clamp-on "amprobe" type gadget would be helpful.

Comment: What causes over-current in these motors? If one would *over*load the motor that would cause over-current, right? Does under-loading leading to over-speeding cause damage to the bearings (without over-amperage) or maybe wreck the motor by causing the armature to hit the fixed parts?

Comment: To Jim Stewart; an electric motor can be easily overloaded when used with an impeller that has the capability to move a fluid in excess of what it was designed to move. For example, If a fan blower is removed from the furnace/air-handler the result is usually that the fan will overload since the resistance to flow has been removed; the ducts resistance is no longer present. and the fan will try to move more air than it normally will when a resistance is applied. Thus , the motor will draw more amperage and will usually overload. The same is true if the impeller is moving almost any fluid.

Comment: Ran out of space: Most  unloaded motors can only run at the RPM it was designed to run at, thus at a no load speed the motor runs at it's design speed with no ill effects. I said most motors since there are a lot of pretty smart electricians that would take me "to task " if I said all motors since there are some that will keep increasing speed until they self destruct.